# WCF Service endpoint address uses https, does that mean the transport level authentication is Certificate?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I am consuming a WCF web service which has an endpoint protocol `https`. Does this mean I need a client certificate to authenticate?

I haven't been given a certificate to use but rather a Username and Password which as I understand it you also need to authenticate but at message level?

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: You need a certificate for authentication

Comment: @Prabu Do you have a source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you won't need a certificate.

By giving you a usernamne and password they are allowing you to connect using HTTP Basic Authentication. Using the HTTPS protocol is preferred when using HTTP Basic Authentication as the credentials is encrypted instead of just base64 encoded when using normal HTTP protocol.

The username and password will be sent with each request in the Authorization header.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775(v=vs.110).aspx#Client) is the MSDN article explaining Basic Auth and C# code examples.

[This Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) also gives a pretty good simple explanation of HTTP Basic Auth

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. You're correct I didn't need a client certificate, my issue was down to an IP whitelist in the end.